# Vertical alignment with a jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

I recently tried to use the plugin particle ground in my project.

But I have a problem: the vertical alignment of the contents inside.

Here's an example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58auo5kL/2/).

```
<div id="particlebg">

        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 home-title">
              <h1>An example of vertical align</h1>
              <h3>An example of vertical align</h3>
              <button class="btn-lg btn-alt">Download</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>  <!-- end #particlebg -->
```

Does anyone know how to do?

**Thanks in advance to all**

Comment: *"vertical alignment of the contents inside*" - The contents inside seems to be moving constantly... what exactly are you trying to align..?

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... I would like to align the div container

Comment: the div container has `100%` height of it's parent, so there is no space left to align. Please update the question explaining what exactly you're trying to do...

Comment: Hello , I'm sorry but I did not understand what you mean .
I wold like to vertically center the div.container in #particlebg

Comment: the height of both `#particlebg` and container is the same. Then how will you vertically center align one inside another?

Comment: Sorry you're right, I modified by removing the height of the container

Comment: Please update it in the question accordingly..

Comment: ok, sorry for this problems

Answer (score 0):

```
#particlebg {
    position: relative;
    height: 350px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}


#particlebg .row  {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

There you go. Pretty sure this is what you want.